# The best way to "add" arrays in this case

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays of the same dimension. Each value in arrays is a number **a** or **b**.

What's the fastest way to get `$array3` of the same dimension which contains:

a, if both values are a,

b, if both values are b,

0, if the values are different.

```
$array1 = array(a,b,b,a,a,b,a,b,a,a,b,b,a);
$array2 = array(a,b,a,b,a,a,b,a,b,b,a,b,a);
==================
$array3 = array(a,b,0,0,a,0,0,0,0,0,0,b,a);
```

What about performance, I believe using loop statement is not the best way.

I belive something like `60&13 = 12` could be used in a proper way but I don't know neither the way nor how to use it for arrays nor how to use it for big numbers (if the array is huge).
Or, using anonymous functions would be the best?

Any ideas for the best (but not least) solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A loop would almost certainly be the best way here. You don't need anything fancy:

```
$items = min(count($array1), count($array2));
$array3 = array_fill(0, $items, 0); // initialize as all zeroes

for($i = 0; $i < $items; ++$i) {
    if ($array1[$i] === $array2[$i]) {
        $array3[$i] = $array1[$i];
    }
}
```

This is going to be *much* faster than `array_map` because function calls are relatively expensive in PHP.

If you want better performance than this then your first consideration should be substituting an [`SplFixedArray`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) for `$array3`:

```
$array3 = new SplFixedArray($items); // and the rest as above
```

Comment: If we speak about perfomance, please don't call `count` every time:)

Comment: @RiaD: Touche. Edited. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You may use `array_map`

```
$array3 = array_map(function($x, $y) {
    return $x == $y ? $x : 0;
}, $array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Thought I'd add an alternate method, using `array_diff_assoc`

```
$temp = array_diff_assoc($array1,$array2); //array of elements in array1 that aren't the same as array2
$temp = array_combine(array_keys($temp),array_pad(array(),count($temp),0)); //replace the values with 0s
$array3 = $temp + $array2; //merge the arrays
ksort($array3); //put the elements back in order
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array3 = array_intersect_assoc($array1, $array2);
$array3 = array_replace(array_fill(0, count($array1), 0), $array3);
```

Comment: I liked this solution, +1 for being inventive.